# How to overwrite magento Catalog search Result controller?

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers

Here is my config.xml file configurations.

```
<global><rewrite>
            <secondarysearch>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/catalogsearch/result/#]]></from>
                <to>/secondarysearch/result/</to>
            </secondarysearch>
        </rewrite>        
    </global>


    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <secondarysearch>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>EF_Secondarysearch</module>
                    <frontName>secondarysearch</frontName>
                </args>
            </secondarysearch>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

It's going to page not found when i'm searching.Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to override the Catalog Search controller, I would advise using this method instead:

```
<config>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
       <catalogsearch>
          <args>
            <modules>
              <namespace_module before="Mage_CatalogSearch">Namespace_Module</namespace_module>
            </modules>
          </args>
       </catalogsearch>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```